# Error android after update react native, I can't open the App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvq8H.png)

I have this problems. My build SUCCESSFUL, but I see this. IOS ios worked. Please help.

Comment: If you can more information about this error, I can give

Comment: Unintelligible, and not a real question

Answer (score 0):

You should import locale-data like below.

```
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en'
```

or

```
require( 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en' )
```

Comment: Where? I don't understand

Comment: Can you share more details?